# How do I horizontally and vertically center a textbox from the bottom border of the navigation menu to the end of the banner image?

Tags: css, textbox, center

How do I horizontally and vertically center a textbox from the bottom border of the navigation menu to the end of the banner image on a responsive website?
I would appreciate any suggestions.

I updated the changes. It is now centered.

CSS Media Queries min-width 768: Contain 
[image]

CSS Cover:
[image]

CSS Contain: 
I prefer this background because the whole image is showing up. However, I cannot get this method to work because I cannot get the fontbox to be centered between the navigation's yellow bottom border and the bottom of the banner image.  Also if I increase the browser size, the background image will not take up the width of the browser.
[image]

banner's background image: 
[image: banner's background image]

Original JSFiddle:
    https://jsfiddle.net/4enbjpyz/

Update JSFiddle: 
    https://jsfiddle.net/me37hnvs/

This is what I have:

Bootstrap HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="bannerHeader">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark" id="myNavmenu">
            <a class="navbar-brand d-md-none ml-auto" href="#" id="menu">Menu</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" id="TEST" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item pr-3"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Nav 1</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="payment.html">Nav 2</a></li>
                </ul>
           </div>
        </nav>  

        <div class = "d-flex">
            <div class = "container justify-content-center fontBox pl-4 pr-4 pt-3">
                <h3>Heading</h3>      
                <p>Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="container bg-white">
    <p>This is some text.</p>      
    <p>This is another text.</p>      
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

body { 
    background: #fff;
}

.container-fluid {
    padding:0;
}

.bannerHeader { 
    /* background-color: I normally use a different color, however I used a red background to show there is no negative space (red) */  
    background-color: #fe0808;
    background-image: url("../images/banner.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    height: 450px;
}

#myNavmenu {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

/* Center Horizontal and Vertically */
.fontBox { 
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    color: #fff;;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 58%; 
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -58%);
    width: 90%;
} 

p {
    font-size: 16px;
}

/* Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)*/
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .bannerHeader { 
        background-position: center top;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 0;
        padding: 0;
        /* aspect ratios: divide the height of the original image by it's own width, and multiply by 100 to get the percentage value */
        padding-bottom: 52.33%; 
        position: relative;
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you solved it  ?

Comment: You have forgotten to put the banner image in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<img>` tag has some special behaviours in comparison with other tags. In your case I suggest you to use a `div` (or maybe `figure`) tag and attach the banner as background image and then set any CSS attribute to control the image behaviour. Then you can use css flex box to center the box. Also you can use CSS `calc()` method if the height of the navigation and the font box are fix. The sudo example could be like this:

```
top: calc(100% - ({navigationHeight} + {fontBoxHeight}));
```

Do NOT forget to put the font box inside the `figure` tag if you will use this approach.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I updated the changes, and the textbox is centered.  However, the background image is cropped when I increase the browser size.  I used background-size: cover.  How do I fix that problem? @Soheil

Comment: That's the behaviour of Cover. Set background-size: contain; background-position:center and see how it works.

Comment: I used the contain for the media (min-width: 768px)  and the cover for the non media queries, which works. @Soheil

Comment: Great run! :-).

Comment: Although, it is a shame that I cannot fit the whole background image in the smaller media queries without centering the fontbox between the border and end of the banner image.  I think this is the best solution is to crop the image by using background size: cover without sacrificing the layout of the fontbox. @Soheil.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what `Cover` value do.